# Does a bouncing spring possess all types of motion?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

By all types of motion I mean velocity acceleration jerk crackle pop and so on... My intuition behind asking this question in the first place lies in the fact that derivatives of trigonometric functions are repeating. Does this mean that for an object that changes position perfectly in harmony with a trigonometric function, such as a bouncing spring, there is a value for all types of motion there are? If so is there any significance to this?

Comment: Acceleration changes at a sinusoidal rate with respect to time; in fact, acceleration is proportional to displacement, but in the opposite direction, and its rate of change is proportional to velocity, but in the opposite direction. The rate at which _that_ rate changes is proportional to displacement, in the same direction.

Comment: So since u can keep finding higher and higher order derivatives the motion can become of higher and higher order

Comment: In that sense, yes, the order is unlimited. On the other hand, since acceleration is proportional to displacement, you only have to consider displacement and its first two derivatives in order to completely solve the motion analytically.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the bouncing spring follows simple harmonic motion (without a phase constant), then the position $x$ of the spring is given by

$$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)$$

Taking the derivative,

$$v(t)=-A\omega\sin(\omega t)$$

$$a(t)=-A\omega^2\cos(\omega t)=-\omega^2\cdot x(t)$$

$$j(t)=A\omega^3\sin(\omega t)=-\omega^2\cdot v(t)$$

$$crackle(t)=A\omega^4\cos(\omega t)=\omega^4\cdot x(t)$$

$$pop(t)=-A\omega^5\cos(\omega t)=\omega^4\cdot v(t)$$

So simple harmonic motion in general *does* have a value for all types of motion.